# Importing QoH in Odoo 8

Tags: import, odoo

Documentation for the new version of Odoo (OpenERP) is nearly non-existent.  Apparently, the process for importing Quantity on Hand for products has changed, and I can't find anything that describes the new method. Anyone know how to import current stock levels into Odoo 8? In version 7, you created an inventory count record, then imported all your product quantities using the reference field from the manually created count record. This doesn't seem to work in v8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I figured out is that you have to have all of your stock locations set up first, so that you can import the quantity on hand *per location* in Odoo 8.  Set up your location hierarchy, then export the IDs.  Merge these with the product variant (*product.template*, not *product.product*) IDs.  I used FileMaker Pro to do this.  Next, create your inventory adjustment record and export the name and ID fields.  Use these on the ***first line only*** of your CSV file that contains the product quantity/location records to import.

If it helps, these are the column headers that I used in the import screen:

- "Inventories / Location / External ID"
- "Inventories / Checked Quantity"
- "Inventories / Product Unit of Measure"
- "Inventories / Product / Database ID"
- "Inventories / Product Name"

Hopefully, that will help someone out.  My notes are a couple months old, so I hope they are correct!

Answer (score 3):

It's finally solved,  simply follow the step

**Step – 1 ;**

**1->**   select product in warehouse module  (open in list view).

**2->**  select the product which you want to update the inventory  .

**3->** click on more button and export  column

i-> product name and any other one if you needed .

you have file with name of **product.temlate.csv** .

**4->** Add a column qty and enter the quantity of product .

**Step – 2;**

**1->** select inventory adjustment in warehouse module  .

**2->** if you already have any created inventory then  go to 3rd point if not then create a inventory and feel the detail . and select all product option in Inventory of - :

**3->** now again click on inventory adjustment and select the inventory.

**4->** click on more and export the following column

***Inventories/location***

***Inventories/product***

***Invevtories/product Unit of Measure .***

Now you have one more file with name **stock.inventory.csv**

**Step -3 ->**

**1->** now add two column on **stock.inventory.csv**

First one is ***name*** and second is ***line_ids/product_qty***.

**2->** delete the value of column ***line_ids/product_id/id***    of **stock.inventory.csv**  file .

now copy the values of ***id*** column from **product.template.csv**  and paste into the ***line_ids/product_id/id***   column of **stock.inventory.csv**  .

**3->**  now copy the values of ***qty*** column from **product.template.csv**  and paste into the ***line_ids/product_qty*** column of **stock.inventory.csv**  .

**4->** enter any value in ***name*** column for your reference .

**Step – 4-**

make sure your file look like this file:-

Click on following link to see file

This is a sample of the succesfully imported data

http://bit.ly/odoocsv

***AFTER IMPORTING DONT FORGET START INVENTORY***

Answer (score 0):

I found that I had to do the import as before, but afterwards, I had to change the state to 'confirm' in the database manually, something like:

```
sudo -u postgres psql -c "UPDATE stock_inventory SET state = 'confirm' WHERE name like 'Inventory1234'" database_name
```

Otherwise, when I would press **Start Inventory**, the quantities would be lost.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I did eventually figure out how to get the import to work.  It's more involved than V7.  I'll explain what I did in an answer below.